# Strong encryption SQL Server 2005-2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I've read the posts here about trigger encryption with `WITH ENCRYPTION` keyword, but it's useless with all the decrypt tools on the network.

There are some other ways to encrypt the triggers?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to protect your business logic, use SQL CLR if basic encryption and an agreement with your customers are not enough. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2.aspx

Quite frankly, and this is not meant as a slight towards you, but there is very little you could do in a T-SQL trigger these days that would take a whole lot to reverse engineer, even if users couldn't get access to the code. Taking this logic out of the database altogether is probably the best way to protect it.

Comment: mmm thank you, so with this I can deploy a sql project inside Sql server. Inside that project I can encrypt/decrypt the trigger.sql file  with a password key stored in a secure place.

Does that makes sense? I think it can work